# sed not working as expected, but only for directory depth greater than 1

Tags: linux, sed, find

I am trying to find all instances of a string in all files on my system up to a specified directory depth. I then want to replace these with another string and I am using 'find' and 'sed' by piping one into the other.

This works where I use the base path as cd /home/../.. or any other directory which isn't "/".  It also only works if I select a directory depth of 1 (so /test.txt is changed, but /home/test.txt isn't) If I change nothing else and used say a depth of 2 or 3, neither /test.txt nor /home/text.txt are changed.  In the former, no warnings appear, and in the latter, the results below (And no strings are replaced in either of the files).

Worryingly, it did work once out of the blue, but I have no idea how and I can't recreate the results.  I should say I know the risks of using these commands with root from base directory, and the specific use of the programs below is intentional so I am not looking for an alternative way, just a clue as to how this isn't working and perhaps a suggestion on how to fix it.

```
cd /;find . -maxdepth 3 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/teststring123/itworked/gI'

sed: couldn't open temporary file ./sys/kernel/sedoPGqGB: No such file or directory
sed: couldn't open temporary file ./proc/878/sedtqayiq: No such file or directory
```

As you see, there are warnings, but nether the less I would expect it to work, the commands appear good, anything I am missing folks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be:

```
find / -maxdepth 3 -type f -print -exec sed -i -e 's/teststring123/itworked/g' {} \;
```

Although changing all files below `/` strikes me as a very bad idea indeed (I hope you're not running as root!).

The "couldn't open temporary file ./[...]" errors are likely to be because `sed`, running as your user, doesn't have permission to create files in `/`.

My version runs from your current working directory, I assume your `${HOME}`, where you'll be able to create the temporary file, but you're still unlikely to be able to replace those files vital to the continued running of your operating system.

Comment: Hi John, could you talk me through my error?  (I am being very careful, I know what you mean though). I am running as root.

Comment: Also, can I ask if you have spotted why my term doesn't work as intended, and what yours now has changed technically to enable it to work (sorry for my ignorance).

Comment: I tried your one, and I got this error John, find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: ok with the new command I get a lot of scrolling of:     sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unknown option to `s'.  I have all the standard files from default linux installation with my added test.txt

Comment: My closing `'` was in the wrong place. What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: I want to riddle this out basically, its now worth more to me to get to the bottom of why this doesn't work than the reason for actually doing it in the first place.  With your new command it gos like how my original string was, albeit with more warnings from other locations, but my teststring files remain the same..  hmm!

like: sed: couldn't open temporary file /sys/power/sedZ8aZfL: No such file or directory

Comment: Ok, it seems to be working through the files, Ill update once its done, hopefully that is it!

Comment: Ok it worked, finally- thank you very much, and I can now sleep well tonight (yep, pretty sad I know lol).

Comment: EDIT: Hmm, now all my files seem to have a copy of themselves with a 'e' suffix lol... -ie wouldn't have anything to do with it would it?

Comment: @user1166981: Yes, the `-ie` is exactly the reason for this. The `-i` option takes an optional "suffix" argument; if supplied, then the `sed` command will create a backup of the files it edits, using that suffix. (Johnsyweb was apparently expecting `-ie` to be the same as `-i -e`. Some options do allow that sort of stacking, but `-i`, because of its optional argument, does not.)

Comment: Thanks @ruakh, I'd not spotted that. I've updated my answer. Again.